How to change folder color in terminal outout shell in macOs also the output have SHEll color code
macOS Sonoma v 14.16.1
When run command to display some files/folders in zsh shell such as Tree
for eg.
> tree . -L 2 -a -I .git

output

you can see in image that folder name comes in very dark in my selected profile (Ocean).
I have changed the profile but still selected (or we can say highlighed ) folder name are not visible.
so asking what is the setting of Terminal ; under Background we can change the colors but again the selected folder are in every theme is not visible
additional question
when save outout as text using Tree
> tree -L 2 -a -I .git -o out.txt

it have some anscii code such as
├── [34;40m.vscode[0m
│   ├── [31;40mcspell.json[0m
│   ├── [34;40mdictionaries[0m
│   ├── [31;40mextensions.json[0m
│   ├── javascriptreact.json
│   ├── [31;40mmarkdownlint.json[0m
│   ├── packagejson.json
│   ├── settings.json
│   ├── [31;40mtasks.json[0m
│   └── template.code-snippets

although I have custom settings to set colors but this is not  a color which I have set
is there any option in Tree which save output without these special characters or is there anything I have tio fix in terminal config to stop outout these code ?

found anser for both

change selection color

open terminal

Setting > Profiles > Text tab

under ANSI Colors :
Note: only first 2 color boxes are responsible for change of folder color and background around folder ( AFAIK )


using -n option will remove color code

>tree -L 3 -an -I '.git|.vscode' -o tree.txt        

